# Динамическая передача параметров из базы данных SQL в url

Tags: java, mysql, spring, request

У меня есть база данных, в которой лежат данные зарегистрированных пользователей. Мне нужно брать данные пользователя, который авторизовался на сайте, и добавить их в url адрес, чтобы работал @RequestParam, который я добавил в контроллер.(url адрес должен динамически создаваться таким - **localhost:8080/schedule?age={age}**. 
**Мой контроллер:**

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping("/page")
    public String schedulePage(@RequestParam("age") int age, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", customUserDetailsService.listAllUsers());
        return "Page";
    }
}
```

**Entity-класс(таблица из БД):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String passwordof;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int age;

    Геттеры и сеттеры.
}
```

**Репозиторий:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.login = ?1")
    User findByLogin(String login);
}
```

**Сервис:**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public List<User> listAllUsers(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repository.findByLogin(login);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Login does not exist");
        }
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

В репозитории и сервисе хранятся методы для авторизации пользователя. Также есть класс, который реализовывает Спринговый интерфейс UserDetails. Каким способом лучше это сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам на постоянной основе нужно чтобы во все урлы подставлялись параметры пользователя, пока он авторизован - вам проще запомнить их через сессию,

```
@PostMapping 
public String login(HttpServletRequest request){
   //....
   request.getSession().setAttribute("user",user);
   return "index";
}

@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("/page")
public String schedulePage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    User user=(User)request.getSession().getAttrubute("user");
    model.addAttribute("currentUserAge", user.age());
    model.addAttribute("users", customUserDetailsService.listAllUsers());
    return "Page";
}

@GetMapping
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request){
    request.getSession.invalidate();
    return "login";
}
```

Либо, обогатить вашу реализацию UserDetails нужными данными, и тогда вы сможете получать текущего принципала одной строкой и кастовать его к вашей реализации:

```
 @GetMapping
 @RequestMapping("/page")
 public String schedulePage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
     MyCustomUser user = (MyCustomUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
     int age = user.age();
     ....
 }

 public class MyCustomUser implements UserDetails{
      private final User dbUserEntity;
      ...
      public int age(){
         return dbUserEntity.age();
      }
 }
```